# Reshape dataset for trading orders using pandas

Tags: python, pandas

I have a dataset for trading positions, where each order is presented in 2 rows with sell/buy row and close row:
(In below example, order #1 is `sell` in row 0 and `close` in row 6)

```
        order time order type  order N.  order size  order price  order profit  balance
0  2020.11.04 00:00      sell        1        0.01      1.17128           NaN      NaN
1  2020.11.04 00:10       buy        2        0.01      1.17125           NaN      NaN
2  2020.11.04 00:45     close        2        0.01      1.17232           1.0    201.0
3  2020.11.04 01:03      sell        3        0.02      1.17328           NaN      NaN
4  2020.11.04 01:31      sell        4        0.02      1.17528           NaN      NaN
6  2020.11.04 02:38     close        1        0.01      1.17261          -1.4    199.6
7  2020.11.04 02:38     close        3        0.02      1.17261           1.2    200.8
8  2020.11.04 02:38     close        4        0.02      1.17261           5.2    206.0
```

I want to reshape so that each order become in one separate row instead of 2 rows:

```
#desired output:

order N.  buy/sell_time        close_time         order_size    order_type     order_profit   balance
1         2020.11.04 00:00     2020.11.04 02:38   0.01          sell           -1.4           199.6
2         2020.11.04 00:10     2020.11.04 00:45   0.01          buy            1.0            201.0
3         2020.11.04 01:03     2020.11.04 02:38   0.02          sell           1.2            200.8
4         2020.11.04 01:31     2020.11.04 02:38   0.02          sell           5.2            206.0
```

I tried this code but didn't succeed:

```
df.melt(id_vars=['order #'])
```

**EDIT**

some orders numbers has more than 2 entries

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Might be easier to split your data into the buy/sell and close orders, set those df indexes to the order number, rename what you want, and concatenate back together.

```
buy_sell = df.loc[df['order type']!='close'][['order time',
                                              'order size',
                                              'order type', 
                                              'order N.']].set_index('order N.')
close = df.loc[df['order type']=='close'][['order time',
                                           'order profit',
                                           'balance',
                                           'order N.']].set_index('order N.').copy()

close.rename(columns={'order time':'close time'}, inplace=True)

out = pd.concat([buy_sell,close], axis=1).reset_index()
```

Output

```
    order N.      order time    order size  order type        close time    order profit    balance
0         1 2020.11.04 00:00          0.01        sell  2020.11.04 02:38           -1.4     199.6
1         2 2020.11.04 00:10          0.01         buy  2020.11.04 00:45            1.0     201.0
2         3 2020.11.04 01:03          0.02        sell  2020.11.04 02:38            1.2     200.8
3         4 2020.11.04 01:31          0.02        sell  2020.11.04 02:38            5.2     206.0
```

Comment: return error:  Reindexing only valid with uniquely valued Index objects

Comment: How sure are you that every order number only has two entries

Answer (score 1):

If you don't want to split your data as @Chris suggested you need some data munging beforehand and afterwards in order to by able to pivot and get the output you specified:

```
In [40]: df['order type'] = df['order type'].replace({'buy': 'buy / sell', 'sell' : 'buy / sell'}) 

In [86]: df                                                                                                                                                                                                        
Out[86]: 
         order time  order type  order N.  order size  order price  order profit  balance
0  2020.11.04 00:00  buy / sell         1        0.01       1.1713           NaN      NaN
1  2020.11.04 00:10  buy / sell         2        0.01       1.1712           NaN      NaN
2  2020.11.04 00:45       close         2        0.01       1.1723           1.0    201.0
3  2020.11.04 01:03  buy / sell         3        0.02       1.1733           NaN      NaN
4  2020.11.04 01:31  buy / sell         4        0.02       1.1753           NaN      NaN
6  2020.11.04 02:38       close         1        0.01       1.1726          -1.4    199.6
7  2020.11.04 02:38       close         3        0.02       1.1726           1.2    200.8
8  2020.11.04 02:38       close         4        0.02       1.1726           5.2    206.0
```

With this prepared you can pivot:

```
In [75]: df2 = df.pivot(index='order N.', columns='order type', values=['order time', 'order size', 'order profit', 'balance']).dropna(axis=1)                                                                           
Out[75]: 
                  order time                   order size       order profit balance
order type        buy / sell             close buy / sell close        close   close
order N.                                                                            
1           2020.11.04 00:00  2020.11.04 02:38       0.01  0.01         -1.4   199.6
2           2020.11.04 00:10  2020.11.04 00:45       0.01  0.01            1     201
3           2020.11.04 01:03  2020.11.04 02:38       0.02  0.02          1.2   200.8
4           2020.11.04 01:31  2020.11.04 02:38       0.02  0.02          5.2     206
```

This makes the 'order N.' your new index meaning you get one row per 'order N.'. The new columns are the values of 'order type' meaning either 'buy / sell' or 'close'. There are no 'order profit's or 'balance' for 'buy / sell', so these get dropped by `dropna`.

The output labels are still a bit redundant as `pivot` created a multiindex that is only needed for 'order time'. This can be beautified with

```
In [82]: df2.columns = [t[0] if t[0] != 'order time' else ' '.join(t) for t in df2.columns.to_flat_index()]

In [85]: df2                                                                                                                                                                                                       
Out[85]: 
         order time buy / sell  order time close order size order size order profit balance
order N.                                                                                   
1             2020.11.04 00:00  2020.11.04 02:38       0.01       0.01         -1.4   199.6
2             2020.11.04 00:10  2020.11.04 00:45       0.01       0.01            1     201
3             2020.11.04 01:03  2020.11.04 02:38       0.02       0.02          1.2   200.8
4             2020.11.04 01:31  2020.11.04 02:38       0.02       0.02          5.2     206
```

Finally to deduplicate to 'order size' column which is redundant

```
In [89]: df2.loc[:, ~df2.columns.duplicated()]                                                                                                                                                                     
Out[89]: 
         order time buy / sell  order time close order size order profit balance
order N.                                                                        
1             2020.11.04 00:00  2020.11.04 02:38       0.01         -1.4   199.6
2             2020.11.04 00:10  2020.11.04 00:45       0.01            1     201
3             2020.11.04 01:03  2020.11.04 02:38       0.02          1.2   200.8
4             2020.11.04 01:31  2020.11.04 02:38       0.02          5.2     206
```

However, for just two order types this is probably overkill